# Kia Rio Overheating

Tags: kia, overheating, rio

I have a 2012 Kia Rio and lately it has been showing signs the car is overheating.

When I switch off the car and switch it on again it runs fine. I find this very confusing because it does it maybe once in 3 days. I took it to the dealer to have it checked and all the checks come back negative. Is there maybe some air trapped in the cooling system? I am suspecting this because I realized my radiator cap was old and replaced it. The other mechanic I took it to said the gasket is blown, but I don't see any symptoms that suggest a blown Gasket. Please help.

Comment: You aren't really giving us enough information to begin answering a question. How does it run *before* you switch it off? What are the actual symptoms of your issues? No check engine lights? How is it behaving differently than normal?

Comment: could be a bad temp sensor too, causing these intermittent issues?

Comment: @Paulster2, the engine is not behaving differently than normal other than the temperature light randomly coming on. Sometimes i can drive the car for 3 or 4 days without the light coming on. There are no check engine lights also. So in short the only symptom is the Temperature light.